# Simple Trigger not working

Tags: apex, trigger, compile-error

I am fairly new to salesforce and I am having a bit of trouble with apex code.

```
trigger HelloWorld on Lead (before update) {
    for (Lead 1 : Trigger.new) {
        1.FirstName = 'Hello';
        1.LastName = 'World';
    }

}
```

I am trying to run the code above and I keep getting the error

> Error: Compile Error: expecting an equals sign, found '1' at line 2 column 14

What does the error mean and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: Change the 1 to an l in all places where you have 1

Answer (score 0):

Variable should not start with number. You are using 1 so compilation error.